# what can be used instead of QRectF?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm beginner for Qt and I'm developing a GUI widget application for my project. I copied the code from a very old project, and, when compiling my project, I get this error:

> error: ": C2661: 'QRectF::QRectF' : no overloaded function takes 3 arguments"

The code generating the error is:

```
*animation -> setEndValue(
    QRectF(
        cos(angleUnit * i) * scale + xShift,
        sin(angleUnit * i) * scale + yShift,
        buttonSize
    )
);
```

Qt documentations are against to use `QRectF`, so in my case what can I use instead of `QRectF`?

Comment: "Qt documentations are against to use QRectF": where did you see that?

Comment: You are missing the `height`... I doubt this ever compiled...

Comment: Maybe better question: What type is `buttonSize`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your code, it is expecting something like:

```
QRectF(qreal x, qreal y, QSizeF size)
```

Indeed, there is no such constructor in the [documentation of `QRectF`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf.html). However, you can use one of the existing constructors:

```
QRectF(const QPointF &topLeft, const QSizeF &size)
```

Can be used by passing your `x` and `y` values as a `QPointF`:

```
QRectF(
    QPointF(
        cos(angleUnit * i) * scale + xShift,
        sin(angleUnit * i) * scale + yShift
    ),
    buttonSize
)
```

On the other hand:

```
QRectF(qreal x, qreal y, qreal width, qreal height)
```

Can be used by passing your `buttonSize` as `with` and `height` values:

```
QRectF(
    cos(angleUnit * i) * scale + xShift,
    sin(angleUnit * i) * scale + yShift,
    buttonSize.width(),
    buttonSize.height()
)
```

Comment: i re-code and try in so many ways, i'm using Qt 5.7. when i read Qt documentation they mentioned that QRectF as an obsolete/deprecated one, here is link i read " http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/obsoleteclasses.html " 

Actually my need is to animate my widget properties, for example stacked widgets must to be changed with a transition or fade effect. I know it would be better to use Qt Quick but my project objective is to complete by using Qt widget application. so please help me to overcome this issue. thanks in advance.

Comment: @Yana you misunderstood the documentation you pointed: QRectF is **not** a deprecated class, but is a class with deprecated members. See [this link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrectf-obsolete.html) for a list of QRectF's obsolete functions. The class by itself is still valid and can be used, assuming you're using it apropriatly as detailed in my answer

Comment: thank you so much, yes i understand the document wrongly but i still have errors when compiling what data want i sent to solve in this case??

Comment: @Yana edit your question. **Do not change any word of your original question.** Add a new paragraph showing your actual code, and the error(s) you get